# how to improve this stripTag function for javasscript with exeception

Tags: javascript

I want to improve this simple function of striptags(from prototype.js) but with an exception.

```
function stripTags(string) {
    return string.replace(/<\w+(\s+("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])+)?>|<\/\w+>/gi, '');
}
```

this basically replace any tags in a string. But I would like to create it as a function a list of tags that should not be strip.

something like

```
stripTags('string with html', [br,i,b,p]);
```

So tags like <br/>,<i>,<b>,<p>

must not be stripped by the function.
Any help can be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripTags(string) {
   return string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
}
```

Check this may help you..

Comment: I don't think this what I'm talking about. How can I exclude such tags to be strip?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another format of String.replace function, like this:

```
function stripTags(str) {
    return str.replace(/(<(\w+)(?:\s+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])+)?>)|(<\/(\w+)>)/gi, replacer);
}

var notTrimSet = ["br", "i", "b", "p"];
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    var tag = p2 || p4;
    if (inArray(tag, notTrimSet)) {
        return p1 || p3;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

function inArray(str, arr) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i] === str) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var html = "<div id=\"123\">test<p></p><b>test2<div></div></b></div>";

console.log(stripTags(html));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/richie_guo/bUanp/1/